# Elastic net visualization

Tags: r, data-visualization, elastic-net, regularization

Is there a way to display in a graph the elastic net (or penalized regression in general) results?
Specifically, how can I render the coefficients of the variables?

Comment: If I remember correctly you just use `plot(model)`, if we are talking about the `glmnet` package.

Comment: `?glmnet::plot.glmnet` tells you that you can plot a coefficient profile plot. Is this what you are looking for? If not, what do you want to plot?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yes, that's it, thank you. I need a way to plot the coefficients "weight" in the model. I'll edit the question to clarify. Seems like I overlooked the simplest solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to specify 2 parameters for the use of elastic net:

1) `lambda` which determines how you combine ridge and lasso regression (this is the parameter special to elastic net and is often the one which you find getting (2d-)plotted in analyses: [here](https://www.slideshare.net/DerekKane/data-science-part-xii-ridge-regression-lasso-and-elastic-nets), [in this presentation](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66783-generic-function-to-perform-logistic-regression-using-elastic-net-regularization), )

2) `alpha` which determines the impact of the penalty term
(this is also sometimes found to be plotted: [here](https://www.google.de/search?q=elastic%20net&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYxaKK1MndAhUBKCwKHTxAAnsQ_AUIDigB&biw=2100&bih=1136#imgrc=WpcGQoKkKVL2IM:))

But of course you are not limited to that. You can combine both accepting a potentially worse readability. Together with the classifier performance you can do a 3d-wireframe-plot with alpha and lambda as x- and y- axis and the performance being plotted as z.

Comment: Ok, I updated, but alpha is only responsible for the impact of the penalty term in general: this would be applied for all regularization methods like ridge and lasso, wouldnt it? The parameter special to elasticnet was lambda afaik.